# Spring logs missing in WAS7

Tags: spring, log4j

I'm facing this issue for quite some time now. I have an EAR deployed in IBM WAS version 7. My application is spring based and it is not logging any spring related info in the console or in the log file.

I have verified the following,

1. log4j.properties is injected as a bean. A log file is getting created as mentioned in the properties file and it logs only the java logging statements not even a single spring log.
2. I have packaged log4j-1.2.14.jar with the application. I have included commons-logging.jar and commons-logging-api.jar along with it (The same issue without the commons jars)
3. We are using ANT as our build tool.

Can anyone guide me where Iam going wrong?

Here is my log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL, console, File
```

## Console Appender

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=[%5p] [%t %d{hh:mm:ss}] %X{traceID}-(%F:%M:%L) %m%n

## Rolling File Appender

log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.File.maxFileSize=10000KB
log4j.appender.File.maxBackupIndex=20
log4j.appender.File.File=C:\logs\new\app.log
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} | %-5p | %c | %X{traceID} | %t | %m%n
log4j.appender.File.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.File.Append=true

## Custom assignments

log4j.logger.endpoint=DEBUG,console,File
log4j.logger.controller=DEBUG,console,File
log4j.logger.handler=DEBUG,console,File

## Disable additivity

log4j.additivity.endpoint=false
log4j.additivity.controller=false
log4j.additivity.handler=false
log4j.additivity.dao=false
log4j.additivity.loggingInterceptor=false

## log4j.additivity.org.springframework=false

Comment: I think, the problem would be most likely with the appender and log level.

Comment: I have added the my log4j config file entry in my post.

Comment: Is it WAS Base or WAS Network Deployment? The latter "steals" some logs. To see them, check the WAS logging configuration and look at its log files instead of the application log file.